# What does comma do in this string sequence?

Tags: ruby

```
end1 = "C"
end2 = "h"
end3 = "e"
end4 = "e"
end5 = "s"
end6 = "e"
end7 = "b"
end8 = "u"
end9 = "r"
end10 = "g"
end11 = "e"
end12 = "r"

puts end1, end2, end3, end4, end5, end6, end7, end8, end9, end10, end11, end12
```

Does the comma mean the next string would be printed on the next line of the previous string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comma separates the arguments of the call to the `puts` method. In other words the `puts` method is called with 12 arguments here.

The `puts` method is defined to print out each argument followed by a line break (unless the given string already ends with a line break), so yes, each string will be printed on a separate line.

If you want to print each string on the same line, you can use the `print` method instead of `puts`.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation. Hope this isn't a stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

comma means apply puts on all the variable. and Whenever puts prints out text, it automatically prints out a newline after the text. Yes it will add new Line after each variable.

Comment: If you're saying that calling `puts end1, end2, etc` will not print each argument followed by a line break, I urge you to try it out. It does.

Comment: yes corrected Puts automatically add NewLine else u can use print